# webpack4 sideEffects:false cause compile error

Tags: webpack-4

when set `sideEffects=false` causes `module.id==null` then throw exceptions, how to solve that?

> RuntimeTemplate.moduleId(): Module D:\mobile-chat\node_modules\happypack\loader.js?id=jsx!D:\mobile-chat\node_modules\@xxx\configs\app\index.js has no id. This should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Webpack `v4.10.0` or later?

I belive there's [an issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7425) in the latest Webpack release that was giving me a similar error in `production` mode.

Try downgrading to `v4.9.2` and run Webpack again.